# System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: 'Not correct assembly name.' error

Tags: dll, .net

I'm trying to decompile a dll using dnspy and changing the method names to my own name. The dll compiles sucessfully, but i get this error when i call any method - System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: 'Not correct assembly name.'